# Is 7zip stdout broken? Is there a way to capture the progress in nodejs? [Windows]

Tags: node.js, 7zip

I am trying to get the stdout of 7zip when it processes files and get the percentage in nodeJs, but it doesn't behave as expected. **7zip doesn't output anything to stdout** until the very end of the execution. Which is not very helpful.. especially when I have large files being compressed and no feedback is shown for a very long time.

The code I am using (*simplified*):

```
// 7zip test, place the 7z.exe in the same dir, if it's not on %PATH%
var cp = require('child_process');
var inputFile = process.argv[2]; if(inputFile==null) return;
var regProgress = /(\d{1,3})%\s*$/; //get the last percentage of the string, 3 digits
var proc = cp.spawn("7z.exe",["a","-t7z" ,"-y" ,inputFile + ".7z",inputFile]);
proc.stdout.setEncoding("utf8");
proc.stdout.on("data",function(data){
    if(regProgress.test(data))
    console.log("Progress = " + regProgress.exec(data)[1] + "%");
});
proc.once("exit",function(exit,sig){ console.log("Complete"); });
```

I have used the **same code to get the percentage with WinRar successfully** and I am beginning to think that **7zip might be buggy? Or I am doing it wrong?** Can I forcefully read the stdout of a process with a timer perhaps?

The same code above, with the exception of the following line replaced, works as expected with WinRar.

```
var proc = cp.spawn("Rar.exe",["a","-s","-ma5","-o+",inputFile+".rar",inputFile]);
```

If anyone knows why this happens and if it is fixable, I would be grateful! :-)

*p.s. I have tried 7za.exe, the command line version of 7zip, also the stable, beta and alpha versions, they all have the same issue*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is no longer needed to use a terminal emulator like `pty.js`, you can pass the `-bsp1` to `7z` to force to output the progress to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

7-zip only outputs progress when stdout is a terminal.

To trick 7-zip, you need to `npm install pty.js` (requires Visual Studio or VS Express with Windows SDK) and then use code like:

```
var pty = require('pty');

var inputFile = process.argv[2],
    pathTo7zip = 'c:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe';

if (inputFile == null)
  return;

var term = pty.spawn(process.env.ComSpec, [], {
  name: 'ansi',
  cols: 200,
  rows: 30,
  cwd: process.env.HOME,
  env: process.env
});

var rePrg = /(\d{1,3})%\r\n?/g,
    reEsc = /\u001b\[\w{2}/g,
    reCwd = new RegExp('^' + process.cwd().replace(/\\/g, '\\\\'), 'm');
    prompts = 0,
    buffer = '';

term.on('data', function(data) {
  var m, idx;

  buffer += data;

  // remove terminal escape sequences
  buffer = buffer.replace(reEsc, '');

  // check for multiple progress indicators in the current buffer
  while (m = rePrg.exec(buffer)) {
    idx = m.index + m[0].length;
    console.log(m[1] + ' percent done!');
  }

  // check for the cmd.exe prompt
  if (m = reCwd.exec(buffer)) {
    if (++prompts === 2) {
      // command is done
      return term.kill();
    } else {
      // first prompt is before we started the actual 7-zip process
      if (idx === undefined) {
        // we didn't see a progress indicator, so make sure to truncate the
        // prompt from our buffer so that we don't accidentally detect the same
        // prompt twice
        buffer = buffer.substring(m.index + m[0].length);
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  // truncate the part of our buffer that we're done processing
  if (idx !== undefined)
    buffer = buffer.substring(idx);
});
term.write('"'
           + pathTo7zip
           + '" a -t7z -y "'
           + inputFile
           + '.7z" "'
           + inputFile
           + '"\r');
```

It should be noted that 7-zip does not always output `100%` at finish. If the file compresses quickly, you may just see only a single `57%` for example, so you will have to handle that however you want.

Comment: It works! Thanks so much. Although I wish it didn't require the visual studio overhead as this adds more hassle to the people I distribute the program to. I am already thinking of dropping 7zip completely because of this small nuisance..

Comment: @ddb722 You could always distribute the compiled versions of the `pty` module with your module/package/whatever and using the appropriate version during runtime.